# How to fix "`?` operator has incompatible types" error in rust

Tags: rust, struct, type-conversion, serde

I have an app in Rust where I want to get a token from a DB server and would store it in a global variable for reusing. I cannot get it running as I have a compiler error, please help me sort it out. I am stuck with it. The code looks like this:

```
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use reqwest::{
    self,
    header::{ACCEPT, CONTENT_TYPE},
    Client,
};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::{
    env,
};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct GeneratedToken {
    app_name: String,
    access_token: String,
    dtable_uuid: String,
    dtable_server: String,
    dtable_socket: String,
    dtable_db: String,
    workspace_id: i32,
    dtable_name: String,
}

impl Default for GeneratedToken {
    fn default() -> GeneratedToken {
        GeneratedToken {
            app_name: "".to_string(),
            access_token: "".to_string(),
            dtable_uuid: "".to_string(),
            dtable_server: "".to_string(),
            dtable_socket: "".to_string(),
            dtable_db: "".to_string(),
            workspace_id: 0,
            dtable_name: "".to_string(),
        }
    }
}

lazy_static! {
    static ref SEATABLE_BASE_URL: &'static str = "https://cloud.seatable.io/api/v2.1/";
    static ref API_TOKEN: &'static str = "token...";
    static ref CLIENT: Client = reqwest::Client::new();
    static ref GENERATED_TOKEN: GeneratedToken = GeneratedToken::default();
}

static mut HAS_TOKEN: bool = false;

async fn get_token() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    unsafe {
        GENERATED_TOKEN = CLIENT
            .get(format!("{}dtable/app-access-token/", *SEATABLE_BASE_URL))
            .bearer_auth(format!("Bearer {}", *API_TOKEN))
            .header(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
            .header(ACCEPT, "application/json")
            .send()
            .await?
            .json::<GeneratedToken>()
            .await?;
        HAS_TOKEN = true;
        print!("Received token: {}", GENERATED_TOKEN.access_token);
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        if !HAS_TOKEN {
            get_token();
        }
    }
}
```

On the `GENERATED_TOKEN = CLIENT` line and the block it follows the compiler throws this error:

```
'?' operator cannot convert from 'GeneratedToken' to 'GENERATED_TOKEN'
```

Comment: Why are you using `static mut`? You should always avoid it, and if you're a beginner you shouldn't even go near.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is indeed confusing. The problem is that `lazy_static` statics are immutable, you cannot assign to them.

If you need a mutable value, you can use a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html). You should also avoid `static mut` and unsafe code, and replace them with mutexes too. And lastly, prefer [`once_cell`](https://docs.rs/once_cell) over `lazy_static`, because the former is integrated into the standard library and part of its API is already available.

You can also replace a bunch of `lazy_static`s with `const`s, which are faster.

You should also use [the blocking API of `reqwest`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/blocking/index.html), because to run async code you need an async runtime, and it's better to avoid async code until you're more settled with Rust.

```rust
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;
use reqwest::{
    blocking::Client,
    header::{ACCEPT, CONTENT_TYPE},
};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::sync::Mutex;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct GeneratedToken {
    app_name: String,
    access_token: String,
    dtable_uuid: String,
    dtable_server: String,
    dtable_socket: String,
    dtable_db: String,
    workspace_id: i32,
    dtable_name: String,
}

impl Default for GeneratedToken {
    fn default() -> GeneratedToken {
        GeneratedToken {
            app_name: "".to_string(),
            access_token: "".to_string(),
            dtable_uuid: "".to_string(),
            dtable_server: "".to_string(),
            dtable_socket: "".to_string(),
            dtable_db: "".to_string(),
            workspace_id: 0,
            dtable_name: "".to_string(),
        }
    }
}

const SEATABLE_BASE_URL: &'static str = "https://cloud.seatable.io/api/v2.1/";
const API_TOKEN: &'static str = "token...";

static CLIENT: Lazy<Client> = Lazy::new(Client::new);
static GENERATED_TOKEN: Lazy<Mutex<GeneratedToken>> =
    Lazy::new(|| Mutex::new(GeneratedToken::default()));

// For advanced users, you can use `AtomicBool` for better performance.
static HAS_TOKEN: Mutex<bool> = Mutex::new(false);

fn get_token() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let generated_token = CLIENT
        .get(format!("{}dtable/app-access-token/", SEATABLE_BASE_URL))
        .bearer_auth(format!("Bearer {}", API_TOKEN))
        .header(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
        .header(ACCEPT, "application/json")
        .send()?
        .json::<GeneratedToken>()?;
    *GENERATED_TOKEN.lock().unwrap() = generated_token;
    *HAS_TOKEN.lock().unwrap() = true;
    print!(
        "Received token: {}",
        GENERATED_TOKEN.lock().unwrap().access_token
    );
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    if !*HAS_TOKEN.lock().unwrap() {
        get_token();
    }
}
```

However, the entire logic of `HAS_TOKEN` is redundant, because this is exactly what `lazy_static` or `once_cell` are for: initializing values on first access. So:

```rust
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;
use reqwest::{
    blocking::Client,
    header::{ACCEPT, CONTENT_TYPE},
};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct GeneratedToken {
    app_name: String,
    access_token: String,
    dtable_uuid: String,
    dtable_server: String,
    dtable_socket: String,
    dtable_db: String,
    workspace_id: i32,
    dtable_name: String,
}

impl Default for GeneratedToken {
    fn default() -> GeneratedToken {
        GeneratedToken {
            app_name: "".to_string(),
            access_token: "".to_string(),
            dtable_uuid: "".to_string(),
            dtable_server: "".to_string(),
            dtable_socket: "".to_string(),
            dtable_db: "".to_string(),
            workspace_id: 0,
            dtable_name: "".to_string(),
        }
    }
}

const SEATABLE_BASE_URL: &'static str = "https://cloud.seatable.io/api/v2.1/";
const API_TOKEN: &'static str = "token...";

static GENERATED_TOKEN: Lazy<GeneratedToken> =
    Lazy::new(|| get_token().expect("failed to get token"));

fn get_token() -> Result<GeneratedToken, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let generated_token = Client::new()
        .get(format!("{}dtable/app-access-token/", SEATABLE_BASE_URL))
        .bearer_auth(format!("Bearer {}", API_TOKEN))
        .header(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
        .header(ACCEPT, "application/json")
        .send()?
        .json::<GeneratedToken>()?;
    print!("Received token: {}", generated_token.access_token);
    Ok(generated_token)
}

fn main() {
    Lazy::force(&GENERATED_TOKEN);
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot it works now. Much of what is happening here is not yet undestood, I will read that book now.